# Many-to-Many association with a twist

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am designing group functionality for doing some common tasks together. So in the application, I have 2 tables, GroupAccount and GroupMembers. GroupMembers has a foreign key relation with GroupAccount. The email-address from GroupMembers is used by Spring-Security for Login. I will post the SQL code at bottom.

Currently with this architecture, A groupMember can be a part of only one GroupAccount. This is not what I want to implement. A groupMember can be a part of multiple GroupAccount. I know you will think many-to-many, but that means replicating the groupAccount or the groupMembers row, but I just want an association. So a single groupMember can be a part of Many groupAccounts and vice-versa, without creating duplicate rows as Spring-Security is involved. I hope I am making it clear. Any suggestions or ideas how to achieve this? If my post is not clear, just tell me, I will make my best effort to explain.

SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE GroupAccount (
                groupid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                groupName VARCHAR,
                adminPassword VARCHAR,
                CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
);


CREATE TABLE groupmembers (
                memberid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                musername VARCHAR,
                mpassword VARCHAR,
                groupid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT memberid PRIMARY KEY (memberid)
);


ALTER TABLE groupmembers ADD CONSTRAINT groupaccount_groupmembers_fk
FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
REFERENCES GroupAccount (groupid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Any pointers are welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: P.S : I am using Postgres with Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you create a junction table for a many to many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE GroupAccount (
                groupid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                groupName VARCHAR,
                adminPassword VARCHAR,
                CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
);

CREATE TABLE GroupMembers (
                memberid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                musername VARCHAR,
                mpassword VARCHAR,
                CONSTRAINT memberid PRIMARY KEY (memberid)
);

CREATE TABLE AccountMembers (
                groupid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                memberid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (groupid, memberid),
                UNIQUE INDEX (memberid, groupid)
);
```

I don't think the syntax is correct for AccountMembers, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Ahh, so you mean to save all the information of which groups user is a part of and vice-versa in the junction table???

Comment: @We are Borg: Yes.  If you want to save the group join time stamp, as an example, that field would go in the junction table.